# Identifying a line in the .bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, errors, compilation-error

I am trying to convert a very large .bib file with approximately 500 references produced by mendeley into a readable text via TexStudio. I've cleaned up all the non latin characters and & signs from titles etc, but there seems to be a problem with two particular lines of the bib file since I get two kinds of errors in those lines:

line 766: Missing $ inserted.

line 766: Missing } inserted.

line 766: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

line 3297: Missing $ inserted.

line 3297: Missing } inserted.

line 3297: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

My question is how can I find these lines in the bib file to check manually for any misplaced characters?

I've tried to open the .bib file with TexWorks, but the line numbers in there seem to be different.

Other suggestions on how to solve this issue are also more than welcome. Thanks!

Below is my code, in case it helps:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openbib]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{apalike}

\begin{document}
    \date{\vspace{-5ex}} % omit date
    \title{Reference List}
    \maketitle
    
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{SystematicLitRev}

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your file is probably (or should be) in UTF-8 (like this site) not the legacy latin-1 encoding, so delete `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`

Comment: Once you start *and continue* 500 entries in a .bib is not large. See e.g., Nelson Bebee's collections (http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/bibliographies.html) for journals or topics e.g., about Fortran (https://liinwww.ira.uka.de/bibliography/Compiler/fortran.html), currently counting about 8k entries (perhaps easier to search on https://liinwww.ira.uka.de/bibliography/Compiler/fortran.html).  Reading the header (http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bib/fortran1.html), depending on the setup available to you *this* (3k entries) might be large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error in the log file will give a lot more information than you are showing, but the line numbers relate to the generated `.bbl` file.

So look at line 766 of xxx.bbl

```
 line 766: Missing $ inserted.
```

you will probably find a `_`  that should be `\_` From there you can see which entry it is, and fix the original `.bib` source for that entry.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am trying to do, but the when I open the .bib file the lines appear to be different.

Comment: @Floyd do as I said in the opening para (I had a typo in So look at..) you want the _bbl_ file not the _bib_ for line numbers: it is the bbl that is read by tex. The error message you have not shown will show the line of text from the bbl not just the  number.

Comment: thank you so much. I was looking at the bib file indeed instead of the bbl. The problem is fixed now.